# How to make catch group (.+?) work as expected in Cucumber Java?

Tags: regex, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I am observing the following when I write Cucumber Java steps for feature file:

Feature file:

```
Then I get result one <result1> and result two <result2> from microservice
```

Java step (stepdefinition)

```
@Then("^I get result one(.+?) and result two(.+?)$")  //step function 1
public void i_get_result_one_and_result_two(String result1, String result2)
        throws Throwable {}

@Then("^I get result one(.+?) and result two(.+?) from microservice$")  //step function 2
public void i_get_result_one_and_result_two_from_ms(String result1, String result2)
        throws Throwable {}
```

Somehow the feature file always map to step function 1 and never to step function 2

The definition of capture group (.+?) as I understand is matching 1 or more of anything (I assume only match to variable in feature file). I do not understand why it does not match to step function 2.

Why does this happen, and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: reorder them so you check function 2 first

Comment: Have a look to my updated answer. It contains now more in detail how the matching is working. Maybe it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation of problem**

As you are using regex here to match your step, it should be noted that `.+` matches any character as many times as possible (with a minimum of 1 character matched).

This itself means that your step:

```
^I get result one (.+?) and result two (.+?)$
```

is [matching everything](https://regex101.com/r/cOa5pR/1) from the last capture group onward.

**Answer**

If you want to keep the capture group only matching the content within quotes, you should instead use:

```
^I get result one '([^']+?)' and result two '([^']+?)'$
```

In here, `[^']+` means match any character that is not a single quote / apostrophe as many times as possible (with a minimum of 1 character matched)

- [Step with "from microservice"](https://regex101.com/r/cOa5pR/3)
- [Step without "from microservice"](https://regex101.com/r/cOa5pR/2/)

(You can also use double quotes in place of single)

Comment: I would suggest not to exclude the single quote in the group. **1)** If one of the both values would contain a single quote, e.g. `O'Reilly`, cucumber would not be able anymore to find the related glue code, **2)** therefore if the value cannot contain a single quote, there is not need to exclude it.

Comment: @SubOptimal Which is why I said you could use double quotes in place of single.

Comment: With `"([^']+?)"` you still can't match `O'Reilly`. To be able you would use something like `"(.+?)"` (and we close to `'(.+?)'`), but then it fails for `foo"bar`. Therefor I suggested to use a surrounding character which cannot be part of the value you want to match. Otherwise Cucumber fails.

Comment: @SubOptimal With `"([^"]+)"` you would be able to. The one you’re excluding from the match is the quote that you are using to separate your step definition from what you are capturing. If you wanted to use a tilde (`\``) instead, you can also do that (for cases where you need to use double quotes inside your capture).

Comment: Which would have the same problem as `([^']+?)` only for a different character. I updated my answer with a more in detail explanation why the surrounding character should not be excluded in the group.

Comment: If you want any character just use a docstring or table instead. But it’s not common for double quotes to appear in a string

Answer (score 1):

You are right with that the pattern `(.+?)` matches a group of any character, occurring one or more times (using the [reluctant quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)). This group ends a the end of the string (the `$` of the part `(.+?)$`).

The pattern `^I get result one(.+?) and result two(.+?)$` match for both strings. I put the parentheses around the matched parts.

```
^I get result one( <result1>) and result two( <result2> from microservice)$
^I get result one( <result1>) and result two( <result2>)$
```

You could either rephrase your steps so the pattern would not match both sentences or you surround the variable field in the step, e.g with a single quote <s>(it must be a character which will never occur in the matched value)</s>, and amend the pattern respectively.

It could look like

```
// steps
Then I get result one '<result1>' and result two '<result2>' from microservice
Then I get result one '<result1>' and result two '<result2>'

// glue code
@Then("^I get result one '(.+?)' and result two '(.+?)' from microservice$")
@Then("^I get result one '(.+?)' and result two '(.+?)'$")
```

**edit** Here some more detailed explanation how the matching is working.

At first the patterns `(.+?)` and `([^']+?)` explained. The `?` qualifier means the search eats the characters from left to right (see the link for the reluctant qualifier).

**^I get result one '(.+?)' and result two '(.+?)'$**

```
^ --- begin of the line
I get result one ' --- a fixed sequence
(.+?) --- any character, one or more times (group 1)
' and result two ' --- a fixed sequence
(.+?) --- any character, one or more times (group 2)
' --- a fixed sequence
$ --- end of the line
```

`group 1` and `group 2` can contain any character, including `'`.

**^I get result one '([^']+?)' and result two '([^']+?)'$**

```
^ --- begin of the line
I get result one ' --- a fixed sequence
([^']+?) --- any character, except the single quote, one or more times (group 1)
' and result two ' --- a fixed sequence
([^']+?) --- any character, except the single quote, one or more times (group 2)
' --- a fixed sequence
$ --- end of the line
```

As soon `group 1` or `group 2` would contain a `'` the line would not be matched anymore.
e.g. `I get result one '<O'Reilly>' and result two '<result2>'`
because `group 1` would be `<O` and then the pattern expects the fixed sequence `' and result two '` which would not match `'Reilly>' ...`.

Some snippets for demonstration

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^I get result one '(.+?)' and result two '(.+?)'$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I get result one '<result1>' and result two '<result>'");
while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("group: %d  subsequence: %s%n", i, matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

**output**

```
group: 0  subsequence: I get result one '<result1>' and result two '<result2>'
group: 1  subsequence: <result1>
group: 2  subsequence: <result2>
```

`group 0` is captured by the entire expression

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^I get result one '(.+?)' and result two '(.+?)'$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I get result one '<O'Reilly>' and result two '<result2>'");
```

**output**

```
group: 0  subsequence: I get result one '<O'Reilly>' and result two '<result2>'
group: 1  subsequence: <O'Reilly>
group: 2  subsequence: <result2>
```

`group 1` matches also the `'` because of `(.+?)` which is embedded between the fixed sequences before and after.

Now the pattern which excludes the surrounding character.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^I get result one '([^']+?)' and result two '([^']+?)'$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I get result one '<result1>' and result two '<result2>'");
```

**output**

```
group: 0  subsequence: I get result one '<result1>' and result two '<result2>'
group: 1  subsequence: <result1>
group: 2  subsequence: <result2>
```

There is no difference to pattern `(.+?)` as the values which should be captured by `group 1` or `group 2` doesn't contain a `'`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^I get result one '([^']+?)' and result two '([^']+?)'$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I get result one '<O'Reilly>' and result two '<result2>'");
```

There is no output because the pattern does not match the line (see the explanation above). This also means that Cucumber would not be able to find a related glue method.

Assume the step is defined in the feature file as

```
Then I get result one '<O'Reilly>' and result two '<result2>'
```

and the glue method is annotated with

```
@Then("^I get result one '([^']+?)' and result two '([^']+?)'$")
```

running Cucumber would raise following exception

```
cucumber.runtime.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step "I get result one '<O'Reilly>' and result two '<result2>'" is undefined
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is also great.